Knowing the date when I saved a post (a Question or an Answer)
In the Saves section of a profile (link pattern https://$community.stackexchange.com/users/saves/$userid/all?sort=Added) there is the "Added" sort option.  But the items in the list don't show when the posts were added to the list.
Is there a way to know the date of when I saved a post (a Question or an Answer)?  Maybe the date can be shown to the left of the 3 vertical dots (the Kebab menu icon) for the list item?

Related: Saved Lists sorted by Activity doesn't display when the latest activity occurred

@ElementsInSpace Looks like you have included my concern in your post ("And if the list is sorted by Added, I suppose it'd be nice to actually see the dates that the items were saved to that list.") except I would suggest that the activity date would be in addition to the asked/answered date, thus the location next to the 3 vertical dots, which (in a recent update) also shows "Saved in $listname" text.
